# JavaFX listview load a wrong image in the custom cell with a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, listview, javafx

I work on my first JavaFX project and have problem with listview custom cell factory. this is my code

```
package ir.sadeghpro.instagram.cell;

import com.ibm.icu.util.PersianCalendar;
import ir.sadeghpro.insta.client.Comment;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextAlignment;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DischargeComment extends ListCell<Comment> {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane pane;

    @FXML
    private TextFlow lblComment;

    @FXML
    private Label lblDate;

    @FXML
    private Label lblTime;

    @FXML
    private Hyperlink lblUsername;

    @FXML
    private ImageView img;


    public static String search = "";
    private FXMLLoader mLLoader;
    private static Map<String, Image> images = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Comment item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);

        } else {
            if (mLLoader == null) {
                mLLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("cell/discharge_comment.fxml"));
                mLLoader.setController(this);

                try {
                    mLLoader.load();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            ObservableList<Node> children = lblComment.getChildren();
            lblComment.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFY);
            children.clear();
            if (!search.isEmpty() && item.getText().contains(search)) {
                int lastIndex = 0;
                for (int index = item.getText().indexOf(search); index >= 0; index = item.getText().indexOf(search, index + 1)) {
                    Text text = new Text(item.getText().substring(lastIndex, index));
                    text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
                    children.add(text);
                    text = new Text(item.getText().substring(index, index + search.length()));
                    text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
                    text.setFill(Color.RED);
                    children.add(text);
                    lastIndex = index + search.length();
                }
                if (lastIndex < item.getText().length()) {
                    Text text = new Text(item.getText().substring(lastIndex));
                    text.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
                    children.add(text);
                }
            } else {
                children.add(new Text(item.getText()));
            }
            PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
            persianCalendar.setTimeInMillis(item.getTimestamp() * 1000L);
            lblDate.setText(persianCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + (persianCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + persianCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            lblTime.setText(persianCalendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + persianCalendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            lblUsername.setText(item.getOwnerUsername());
            Image image;
            if ((image = images.get(item.getOwnerId())) == null) {
                img.setImage(null);
                new Thread(() -> {
                    Image image1 = new Image(item.getOwnerProfilePicUrl());
                    images.put(item.getOwnerId(), image1);
                    Platform.runLater(() -> img.setImage(image1));
                }).start();
            } else {
                img.setImage(image);
            }
            Circle clip = new Circle(25, 25, 25);
            img.setClip(clip);
            lblUsername.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.instagram.com/" + item.getOwnerUsername()));
                } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(pane);
            setHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        }
    }
}
```

my problem is in line 107-114. in this line if image of user not download before I download it and add to hashmap image next add it to view and it's work fine but when scroll list fast maybe 100 image download and because in thread after download image add to cell ImageView even cell disapear and not shown anymore for example I have cell X in index 10 and cell Y in index 25 if I scroll fast some time image of X display in Y cell

sry if I don't explain clearly because it's my first JavaFX project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static Map<String, Image> images = new HashMap<>();

...

Image image;
if ((image = images.get(item.getOwnerId())) == null) {
    img.setImage(null);
    new Thread(() -> {
        Image image1 = new Image(item.getOwnerProfilePicUrl());
        images.put(item.getOwnerId(), image1);
        Platform.runLater(() -> img.setImage(image1));
    }).start();
} else {
    img.setImage(image);
}
```

Caching the images is a good idea, but this way it's done wrong. You load & insert the image to the map on a different thread. Since you don't synchronize the access there is no guarantee that both threads see the map the same way. Also considering the fact that `Image` provides a way of asynchronously loading a `Image`, it's not really necessary to create a thread yourself.
Furthermore for big amounts of data you may want to get rid of images that are not currently used by the GUI. Using `SoftReference`s would be a good idea.
The main issue however is the lack of synchronisation. If you scroll fast enough, multiple threads may load different images for the same cell and you don't know, if the last one to be started is the last one to execute `Platform.runLater`. Multiple images from the same source may be loaded in parallel.
There is no way of reusing your cache either. If the images are needed in some other part of your app, it's impossible to reuse them this way.

My recommendation:

```
...

import java.awt.Desktop; // importing more classes from awt than neccessary could result in problems
...

public class DischargeComment extends ListCell<Comment> {

    ...

    /**
     * Constructor to pass external cache
     * @param cache 
     */
    public DischargeComment(Map<String, SoftReference<Image>> cache) {
        if (cache == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    /**
     * constructor using the default cache
     */
    public DischargeComment() {
        this(getDefaultCache());
    }

    private final Map<String, SoftReference<Image>> cache;

    private static Map<String, SoftReference<Image>> defaultCache;

    private static final URL FXML_URL = DischargeComment.class.getResource("cell/discharge_comment.fxml");

    public static Map<String, SoftReference<Image>> getDefaultCache() {
        if (defaultCache == null) {
            defaultCache = new HashMap<>();
        }
        return defaultCache;
    }

    public static String search = "";
    private boolean loaded = false; // no need for a reference to fxmlloader here

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Comment item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            if (!loaded) {
                FXMLLoader mLLoader = new FXMLLoader(FXML_URL);
                mLLoader.setController(this);

                try {
                    mLLoader.load();
                    img.setClip(new Circle(25, 25, 25));
                    loaded = true;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            ...

            // use single access here
            // also use url as key
            cache.compute(item.getOwnerProfilePicUrl(), (key, value) -> {
                Image image = null;
                if (value != null) {
                    image = value.get();
                }
                if (image == null) {
                    image = new Image(key, true); // load image in background
                    value = new SoftReference<>(image);
                }
                img.setImage(image);
                return value;
            });

            lblUsername.setOnMouseClicked(e->{
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("https://www.instagram.com/" + item.getOwnerUsername()));
                } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(pane);
            setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE); // don't set height to -1
        }
    }
}
```